# Passing array to model?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, variable-assignment

Just to clarify **all the answers** here work flawlessly!  I chose Edwins since he posted first.

```
$this -> load -> model('staff_model');
            $this -> load -> library('encrypt');

            $arrData = array(
                'anum' => $this -> encrypt -> encode($this->input->post('anum')),
                'first' => $this -> input -> post('fname'),
                'last' => $this -> input -> post('lname'),
                'why' => $this -> input -> post('why'),
                'aidyear' => $this -> input -> post('aidyear'),
                'signintime' => NULL,
                'comments' => $this -> input -> post('comments'),
                );

            if ($insert = $this -> staff_model -> session($arrData)) {
                redirect('staff_controller/signin_info');
            } else {
                $this -> studentlogin();
            }
```

Model :

```
function session($arrData) {
    $null = NULL;
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO session (anum, first, last, why, aidyear, signintime, studentcomments) 
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $insert = $this -> db -> query($sql2, $arrData);

    return $insert;

}
```

Comment: Of course you can pass an array to your model. But you need to post your errors and show what you tried.

Comment: Edited the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define array variables like this. Try to change to,

```
$data = array (
                    'encrypted' => $this->encrypt->encode('anum'),
                    'first' => $this->input->post('first'),
                    'last'  => $this->input->post('last'),
                    'aidyear' => $this->input->post('aidyear'),
                    'why' => $this->input->post('why'),
                    'comments' => $this->input->post('comments'),
       );
```

Comment: Still get the  Message: Undefined variable: (what ever variable) error

Comment: INSERT INTO session (anum, first, last, why, aidyear, signintime, studentcomments) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) seems like nothing is passing because all of the values are NULL

Comment: @RaGe10940 you can't use $encrypted, $first etc.. directly. because it is in Array. Change $data['encrypted'], $data['first'] etc..

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
$this -> load -> model('staff_model');
$this -> load -> library('encrypt');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->helper('url');

//validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('anum', 'Anum', 'required');

        other validation rules
                .....

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                  redirect('back to previous page through controller');
        }else{


    $data = array (
                    'encrypted' => $this->encrypt->encode('anum'),
                    'first' => $this->input->post('first'),
                    'last'  => $this->input->post('last'),
                    'aidyear' => $this->input->post('aidyear'),
                    'why' => $this->input->post('why'),
                    'comments' => $this->input->post('comments'),
       );

     if ($insert = $this -> staff_model -> session($data)) {
         print_r($insert);
    }
}
```

Model

```
function session($data) {

        $query= $this->db->insert('session', $data); //insert into session table
            return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller:

```
$arrData = array();
```

//use same name as in your database table in array fileds like this

```
    $arrData['anum'] = $this->encrypt->encode('anum');
    $arrData['first'] = $this->input->post('first');
    $arrData['last'] = $this->input->post('last');
    $arrData['aidyear'] = $this->input->post('aidyear');
    $arrData['why'] = $this->input->post('why');
    $arrData['studentcomments'] = $this->input->post('comments');

  if ($this -> staff_model -> session($arrData)) {
                redirect('staff_controller/signin_info');
  }
```

And in model just use

// No need to write variable names because we already use same field names in array

```
function session($arrData)
     {
       if($this->db->insert($arrData))
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
```